# Problem Pulling Field Info Into Page

Tags: forms, fields, channel-fields

I'm having issues posting fields from individual entries to my sites pages. For example, I'm trying to post a form that changes based on the specific type of page that it's on (my Marketing Automation tool requires different information for each form in the header so that it knows which form is which and how to process it).

What I've done is create a field for my posts that places the correct forms information in the header. This is the code that is in the header.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="no" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" limit="1"}
    {if segment_1 == 'blog'} 

        {post_specific_info}

    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now, what's happening is, it is only pulling the field information from the latest post. I tried removing the limit="1" but then it pulls in the field from every post. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I was missing was that dynamic should have been set to "yes". Once I did that, each post began pulling from it's own data rather than the last post.